# 90s(?) Movie where young boy's virtual girlfriend becomes real

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

I watched a movie in the 90s, I think. I don't remember much from the movie. There was a young boy who has a blond virtual girlfriend with large breasts. I remember a pool scene where they swam around naked.

Then she becomes real in the movie and comes to life. I don't remember the rest. I think it was a thriller type, but I don't know.

Comment: To clarify - the swimming scene took place in virtual reality, before she enters the real world?

Comment: Possibly Weird Science?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - That was my first thought. He could easily be conflating the topless (blond) girl who gets sucked up the chimney

Comment: Live action or cartoon?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I agree, except that [Weird Science](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090305/) was in the 80s.

Comment: @RDFozz yeah thats true bro

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it was a live action movie i am sure

Comment: @DanielRoseman i will check the movie.. i did watch the trailer but couldnt be sure

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the OP could be conflating a memory of [*Weird Science*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Science_(film)) the 1985 American teen comic science fiction movie:

[image: Weird Science movie poster]
<sub>*Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License: Wikipedia 2019.*</sub>

and [*Weird Science*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Science_(TV_series)) the American television sitcom, based on the 1985 film of the same name, that aired on the USA Network from March 5, 1994 until July 25, 1998:

[image: Weird Science TV poster]
<sub>*Attribution IMDB 2019.*</sub>

which went under the title *Code Lisa* in Europe.

[The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Science_(film)#Plot):

> inspired by the 1935 classic Bride of Frankenstein to create a virtual
>   girl using [his friend's] computer; infusing her with everything they can
>   conceive to make the perfect dream woman. After hooking electrodes to
>   a doll and hacking into a government computer system for more power, a
>   power surge creates Lisa, a beautiful and intelligent woman with
>   seemingly endless powers.

That's just the beginning. The plot involves a party, conjoured cars, Lisa ([Kelly LeBrock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_LeBrock)) pulling a gun on the boy's parents, rewriting their memories, grandparents being frozen and put in a cupboard, an enormous missile conjured through the house - a mean older brother being transformed into a giant talking turd. Too much to go into in any coherent detail here.

The [TV  series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Science_(TV_series)#Plot) is much the same but involves the blond actress [Vanessa Madeline Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanessa_Angel) pictured above playing Lisa.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanks for the edit, I'm just getting around to paying attention to the markup possibilities.

Comment: No worries, I was mainly editing to add the double space after the image so the attribution line appears underneath the image. At the same time I added a couple of other things in to make it look "nicer" and go by some informal policies.